# Find number strips in array to match the target array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Let's think we have two arrays

A= {1,2,3,4}
B= {1,3,4,2}

You're asked to get strips of the first array and order it to match the second array and return the minimum number of strips. For the arrays above you should strip {1},{3,4},{2}. So what should be the algorithm/code for this problem?

Comment: Is the first array always sorted?

Comment: You could just strip {1},{2},{3}, {4} right? Is there other criteria, otherwise, just strip every element.

Comment: @yyy Can you explain how the strips are found? What's their criteria? Consecutive elements in order?

Comment: @Dialecticus I think it's sorted

Comment: @PhamTrung you have to choose the way that would require the minimum number of strips

Comment: @vivek_23 You have to choose the minimum number of strips. There is no other requirements

Comment: @yyy If there are no requirements, I think minimum number of strips is 1 containing the whole array!

Answer (score 0):

If array `A` is known to be sorted then you can create an array `B2` whose elements are struct containing int elements from array `B`, and also int index that those elements in `B` are taking. In your example array `B2` would be {{0, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 2}} (here first item in struct is index, and second is value from `B`).

Now sort array `B2` using values from `B`. `B2_sorted` would be {{0, 1}, {3, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}}. You now have elements sorted as in array `A`, but also indexes from array `B`. When you loop through this array note the segments. Two consecutive elements are in the same segment if their indexes from array `B` are also consecutive. Indexes here are 0, 3, 1, 2, and only 1 and 2 are consecutive and make a segment. Two other elements make segments by themselves. So when looking over indexes you have segments {0}, {3}, {1, 2} and when looking over values attached to those indexes you have segments {1}, {2}, {3, 4}.

Your job is just to count those segments. Number of segments is equal to size of array minus number of occurrences where two consecutive elements have consecutive indexes.

If you want to have even faster algorithm you would have to replace sorting with hash maps. I don't know if you know about those, and that is why I didn't use them in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an approach.  Locate the longest available strip, remove it from B, reducing B to either 1 or 2 sets of remaining values, then recursively match each of those subsets, breaking them down further as needed until all members of B have been eliminated.

For example:  `A={2,1,4,2,1,3} B={1,3,2,1,3,4}`

All possible strips would include, `{1},{1,3},{3},{2,1},{2,1,3},{3},{4}`

The longest strip is `{2,1,3}` so it comes out first.
`B = {1,3} + {4}, S = {2,1,3}`

The next longest matching strip for the `{1,3}` half is `{1,3}`.
`B = {4}, S = {2,1,3} + {1,3}`

The next longest matching strip for the `{4}` half is `{4}`.
`S = {2,1,3} + {1,3} + {4}`